# How to wait for a nedb query to finish before resolving? Query sometimes goes out of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, nedb

I'm not new to programming but new to nodejs and webdev so please go easy on me.

I've been sitting on a problem for a while now.

I have user login taking email and password and then user is redirected to a "Projects" page where list of projects is loaded.

**authRoutes.js:**

```
//login
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    _dbo.login(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        .then((user) => {
            var token = jwt.sign({id: user._id}, config.secret, {expiresIn: 86400});
            res.cookie('auth', token);
        }).then(result => {
            res.redirect('/project/');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        });
});
```

on *res.redirect('project/');*

I'm calling *_dbo.getUserProjects(data.id)* which then are displayed on the project page.

**projectRoutes.js**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("redirected");
    var token = req.cookies.auth;
    console.log(token);
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("could not verify");
            res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
        } else {
            console.log("verified");
            console.log(data.id);
            _dbo.getUserProjects(data.id)
                .then((projects) => {
                    console.log("got projects");
                    res.render('projects', {
                            "projects": projects}
                        );
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Error:");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that in DatabseAO.js my *this.Projects.find()* query sometimes does not work because it is not "waited for" and the app gets stuck.

**DatabseAO.js**

```
getUserProjects(userId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.Projects.find({ownerId: userId}, (err, docs) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log("could not find project");
                } else {
                    resolve(docs);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Would anyone be able to help me fix this please and help to explain it like to 11 year old? thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*it is not "waited for"*"? Are you saying the  `this.Projects.find` callback never runs?

Comment: Sorry, I may not explained it properly.   What happens is that: the function continues with trying to render user projects ( in projectRoutes.js - ".then(projects)" ) even when "this.Projects.find()" did not have the time to grab the data from database - the "projects". But it cannot continue because the data comes as "undefined" sometimes.  Hope it makes sense. T

Comment: No, that cannot happen, the `then` callback is not called before the `resolve(docs)` in the `getUserProjects` function - your code is not perfect but it should work. If you're saying it runs nonetheless, then what's the value of `projects`?

Comment: It does work sometimes... , when it works I do get the correct data (user projects), when it does not work the data comes out as "undefined" and the app gets stuck , page keeps trying to load - I guess because it does not get a response.

Comment: What exactly comes out as `undefined`, where does it get stuck, and what parts of your code *did* execute successfully? (Also notice that indeed you do not send a response from the `catch` handler)

Comment: when it does not work (gets stuck):  I have placed a console.log just above "this.Projects.find()" and this is where it just stops (I do get the output from that log),  then the page keeps loading ("waiting for localhost") and I do not get any of the console.log from either if or else blocks that are below

Comment: Then what exactly is that `Projects.find` method?

Comment: it is a nedb query to get projects from database

Comment: If you can make a reproducible example where `Projects.find` does never call its callback, that's a bug in the nedb library.

Comment: Thank you. I was going out of my mind with this. Problem is that it works sometimes and does not work other times (without any changes to the code). Anyway thank you for your time.